# I can't seem to copy and paste commands into my command block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Whenever I try to copy and paste a long command into a command block, it seems to work, but then when I click "done," and then go back into the command block, the command is erased. I don't know what I am doing wrong!

Answer (score 1):

1.8 seems to have an issue with copying and pasting from what I have noticed. I can't even paste into the chat bar...

I would recommend to just take the time and write out the command, besides you will get practice and be able to write it without copying it from a website.

Comment: Typing a command might be good practice for short commands, but more advanced commands are actually easier to type in an external editor and then pasted into minecraft.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are hitting "Done" and not "Cancel"? 1.8 does have a few problems copying and pasting, but 1.8.1 and up should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

How exactly are you doing it? I'll show you how I do it.

Grab a command block, and place it down.
Open it up, and do **CTRL+V** to paste it in the command block. 
Click **DONE**, make sure not to click close.

Are you on a multiplayer server? If you are make sure command blocks are **ON** because if they are not, it will not work.

Also do you have cheats on, or have OP on the server? If you don't, it wont work either.